# In XPath how do I select a node by text no matter which text child has it?

Tags: c#, html, xml, xpath

I have some HTML code like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> John
            <font color="red">
            <b>Unemployed</b>
            </font>
            <br/>ID 12345<b>
            some Text</b>
            <br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

There are some more `tr` in the code but this is just an example
I want to select the `td` node that has an specific ID text so in this case will be 12345.

I could reach the ID with the following XPath:

```
HTML/TABLE/descendant::*[contains(text()[3], '12345')]
```

But I want to avoid the use of the index [3]. I also tried with

```
HTML/TABLE/descendant::*[contains(., '12345')]
```

But that selects the `tbody`.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: are you required to use XPath?

Comment: If XPath not required. You can do it simply with Linq To XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XPath to select a node by text no matter which text child has it, use `//`, `contains()` and `.`:

```
//td[contains(., '12345')]
```

**Explanation**:

- `//td` selects all `td` elements in the document.
- `//td[`*condition* `]` restricts selection to those `td` that satisfy *condition*.
- `.`  is the current node (`td`); inside `contains()` it is the *string value* of the current node:

  ```
   John

              Unemployed

              ID 12345
              some Text
  ```
- `contains()`, given the above string value of `.`, does contain "12345" and so evaluates to true without having to specify the exact text node, as requested.

Comment: Cool man thanks this is working just fine in Chrome search I will try this with my code :)

Answer (score 0):

How about `//td[ contains(., '12345' ) ]` ?

Works for me. Is that what you want?